# ajax request in microsoft teams - desktop application

Tags: ajax, tabs, microsoft-teams

Is it possible to execute ajax request in a page displayed in teams desktop application tab? It seems to work in browser teams app, but not in desktop one.

Comment: Could you please share more information. Are you developing any Teams app for Teams Desktop client?

Answer (score 0):

In the web browser this is easy to test, just load browser debug tools and Network tab. For Desktop this is also possible, you just need to hook up the developer settings - please see this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/developer-tools#access-devtools-on-the-desktop

It also shows developer / debugging on Android, by the way.